# Should SELinux be Permissive to access /dev/diag

Tags: adb, root-access, linux, selinux

I am trying to set the SELinux to permissive on Android with no luck.

I tried the command `su 0 setenforce 0` it returns `OK` while still being Enforcing if checking immediately using `getenforce` command.

I even tried to change the prop.build: this file did not exist instead a prop.build.bak did so i copied it modified the SELinux to 0 instead of 1 and pushed it without the .bak extension. Even i checked with external applications that modify the prop.build where the SELinux is set to 0 but when checking with the `getenforce` command it is still returning `Enforcing`.

My goal is to get access to the /dev/diag which I believe is being denied due to SELinux using Android JNI as:

```
 fd = open("/dev/diag", O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE | O_NONBLOCK);
```

What shall i do?

Update:

When using the command `ls -l /dev/diag` it returns `crw-rw-rw- system   qcom_diag 244,   0 2015-01-14 01:47 diag`.

Here is some dmesg extract

```
here is the extract of the dmesg:

[18177.676603]  [0: servicemanager:  743] avc:  received setenforce notice   (enforcing=1)
[18182.768070]  [1: servicemanager:  743] avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
[18183.231867]  [0:           init:    1] avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
[18183.232006]  [0:           init:    1] avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
```

And tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005670/why-cant-my-android-app-has-root-privilege-access-dev-input to use the open server class with no luck: returning `Server thread forced to quit by error`

As for the ROM I am using the J5-J500H (J500HXXU1AOG4_OXE1AOG4_J500HXXU1AOG4) and Android 6.0.1 as follow: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-root-twrp-samsung-galaxy-j5-2015-2016-prime-variant-marshmallow-6-0-1.3502292/

Hint: I don't think the ROM is the problem because I am using other applications that are being able to access the /dev/diag

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are trying to do. You are performing some random steps which don't relate much. // SELinux may not be set `permissive` on all devices. Explanation here: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A218526+SECURITY_SELINUX_ENFORCING // TWRP and main system (ROM) are two independent operating systems. SELinux state in one doesn't affect the other. // SELinux policy enforcement requires two context. Target context in your case is `u:object_r:diag_device:s0`. What's the source context? From where you want to access `/dev/diag`?

Comment: Did you check `avc` denials in `dmesg`? Which ROM / Android version are you using? Why do you want to remount `/system` RW? // Please state clearly your actual problem, not the steps you are performing to resolve the problem. Be aware of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Comment: Thanks, @IrfanLatif how can I get continuous dmesg? since after the code execution ends If i check the dmesg i am not getting any avc

Comment: As for the ROM I am using the J5-J500H (J500HXXU1AOG4_OXE1AOG4_J500HXXU1AOG4) and Android 6.0.1

Comment: Following these instructions: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-root-twrp-samsung-galaxy-j5-2015-2016-prime-variant-marshmallow-6-0-1.3502292/